# Using Regex to Extract between __italic__ and some other

Tags: ruby, regex

I am writing code to extract some data between (**italic**, --bold--) characters. (Very similar to SO comment feature)

I actually wrote the method for that (using a loop and checking characters), but I wondered if I can re-write that method using Regex.

I tried Rubular, but I am not that good at Regex:

This kinda works for italic, but I think it is not a good solution for using all other special chars (like -- and possibly others)

```
regex: _{2}([^_]*)_{2}
text: __word1__ not_italic __a__ --bolder--
```

Is it possible to do that with a 1 match call and regex, or do I have to crete special regex's for each special formatting characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Here's a nifty construct you can use: `(__|--)((?:(?!\1).)+)\1`

Demo + explanation: http://regex101.com/r/tO4tW1

The content you're after will be in the second backreference every time.

Comment: thank you! It looks like working, but do you think is there a way to make following work too:
`__**word1**__` -> _**word1**_

Comment: ok nevermind, even SO doesn't convert that :) So I think yours would be enough